# Export BigQuery table to GCS as CSV or JSON generates a file type file

Tags: json, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

After running a query and saving the results into a table, I went on exporting its content into a GCS bucket.

When in the table, I clicked Export and the following screen showed up

[image: Export from BigQuery to GCS]

Because the table was bigger than 1 GB, I've used

```
bucketname/all_years*
```

Then, because I wanted it in both CSV and JSON, specified the Export format CSV, started the export and repeated for JSON.

Didn't notice if I got CSV and JSON files inside of the bucket (I deleted it right away due to costs, but my memory tells they weren't .csv / .json already inside of the bucket) and once I downloaded the content from the bucket to my Windows machine, I got a file of type file:

[image: File type file GCS]

To go around this I had to go to every file properties and add .csv / .json and click OK

[image: From file type to CSV]

[image: Now finally .csv]

Why is that even though i specified the export format as .CSV and .JSON I got a file of type file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just setting Export Format controls file format but not file extension - You should explicitly set file extension

So, instead of `bucketname/all_years*` - you should use `bucketname/all_years*.json` for example or `bucketname/all_years*.csv`